# Syntax error or access violation when trying to select distrinct

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb, relational-database

I'm honestly not sure why I'm getting an error since I just moved the two selects to be distrinct and in the left outer join but they were working before in the main opening select statement

```
SELECT body, timestamp FROM chats 
LEFT OUTER JOIN messages ON chats.id = messages.chat_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT sender.first_name AS sender_first_name, sender.last_name AS sender_last_name,
sender.username AS sender_username) users AS sender ON chats.from_user_id = sender.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT reciever.first_name AS reciever_first_name, reciever.last_name AS reciever_last_name,
reciever.username AS reciever_username) users AS reciever ON chats.to_user_id = reciever.id 
WHERE from_user_id = :fromUserId AND to_user_id = :toUserId
```

Also tried doing it with the FROM clause

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT sender.first_name AS sender_first_name, sender.last_name AS sender_last_name,
                                sender.username AS sender_username FROM users) users AS sender ON chats.from_user_id = sender.id
```

Comment: Can you explain what `:fromUserId` means here?  Whence are you executing this query?  The error would seem to maybe not have to do with the syntax but perhaps something else.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am binding it at a later point. That part was working completely fine before I changed the selects to be distrinct and inside the left outer joins.

Comment: Your subqueries does not contain FROM clause.

Comment: It seems `) users` in the subqueries should actually be `FROM users)`

Comment: Hey Gordon this looks very promising. The DISTINCT was supposed to make it so I could get the record for the users once but multiple ones for the chat

Comment: The o.p. is posing a poor query -- I'm guessing a little, because we don't know the schema. I presume `body, timestamp` are not keys to `chat` -- which I guess is `chats.id`. realistically it's unlikely there would be two chats with the same `timestamp` or with the same `body` (and `timestamp`), but it's possible: then do you want to see both in the result? It's much better to be explicit: either `SELECT DISTINCT`, or include `chats.id` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid subquery:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT sender.first_name AS sender_first_name, sender.last_name AS sender_last_name,
 sender.username AS sender_username) users AS sender
```

You haven't explained what the query is supposed to be doing, but I speculate that you want:

```
SELECT body, timestamp,
       us.first_name AS sender_first_name, us.last_name AS sender_last_name, us.username AS sender_username
       ur.first_name AS receiver_first_name, ur.last_name AS receiver_last_name, ur.username AS receiver_username
FROM chats c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     messages m
     ON c.id = m.chat_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     users us
     ON c.from_user_id = us.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     users ur
     ON c.to_user_id = ur.id 
WHERE c.from_user_id = :fromUserId AND c.to_user_id = :toUserId;
```

You should not need `DISTINCT` when joining to a table on the `id`.

Comment: True that you don't always need `DISTINCT`, but it's a good habit to get into, especially for the outermost `SELECT` -- even if you `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to other tables. The problem in the o.p. is there's no `FROM users` inside the nested `(SELECT ...)`, as comments point out. Luckily your answer 'gets away' without nesting; but what if there were a clash of column names amongst the joined tables? This answer looks like "a disaster waiting to happen", to quote somebody round here.

Comment: @AntC . . . It is precisely an *awful*, *terrible*, *horrible* way to write queries.  First, `select distinct` incurs overhead, so it should only be used when necessary.  More importantly, it not should not be used to remove duplicates unless the query-writer thoroughly understands the data and the query and why distinct values might appear.

Comment: Ah, because a newbie asking a q here will of course "thoroughly understand" why there might be duplicate rows, and what the consequences of (say) `COUNT(*)` might mean.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: what overhead, precisely (given the subquery is by id)?

Comment: @david.pfx . . . The overhead to remove duplicate rows in the result set.  That is what `select distinct` does.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Not very precise. What duplicate rows in which result set, and precisely what overhead does that incur?

Comment: `select distinct` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  It is that simple.  `select` does not remove duplicates so there is no such overhead.  Did you downvote this answer?

Comment: Downvoting this answer, because it's not equivalent to the q as posed, which `SELECT`s only `body, timestamp`, neither of which are indexes (I'm guessing). I'm not understanding why the q as posed sub-`SELECT`s all those `_name` columns, because it seems to then throw them away/doesn't `JOIN ... ON` them. So it's a poor question/should not be answered; and this answer is an answer to a question not asked.

Comment: @AntC . . . You should let the OP determine if it is equivalent, because that depends on the data -- and it is most likely not only equivalent but what the OP wants.

Comment: The OP starts with "they were working before ...". If the OP wanted those `_name` columns in the output, they'd be in the outermost `SELECT`. Quite possibly the OP isn't sure what they want; that doesn't entitle you to make high-handed 'corrections' that materially change the output.

Comment: The answer as given correctly identifies the syntactic problem with the query by OP.  (SELECT ... ) users AS ...   should at the very least become (SELECT ... FROM users) AS ...   .  As for the set of selected columns not being equal between Op and answer given, it was very clearly stated that "I ***speculate*** that you want ...".  Perhaps you'd only want to see questions answered here if OP was first able to prove that "the question is correct" ?

Comment: As for OP saying "they were working before", that is referring more than likely to how the query was formulated before OP "just moved the two selects ... in the left outer join" (and messed up while doing that move).  Which is yet another indication that this answerer's guesswork is more than likely not too far off, to put it cautiously.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: another generic answer. In reality the query plan for a join with DISTINCT will typically never create duplicates just to remove the them later, so typically no overhead and often a lower cost query. Your generic advice is mostly wrong, certainly unjustified. Unless you can prove otherwise with a specific example.